# How to create actionsheet using HTML5 and phonegap cordova2.0 for iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, cordova, xcode4.3

I am very new to iPhone development and also am fresh to using PhoneGap Coredova 2.0 for iPhone. Am working in Xcode 4.3. I want to create UIActionsheet in my iPhone app using HTML5 for Phonegap iPhone app. I have used Google but am not find any useful guide from there. Could you please help me to create UIActionsheet using HTML5 and Phonegap for iPhone app? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A UIActionsheet is simple a modal window with options on it. In order to do this in PhoneGap, you need to build out the UI yourself. PhoneGap doesn't do anything for you UI wise. There are many UI frameworks out there. You could look at jQuery Mobile or Sencha. There is even jQuery UI, although that may be a bit heavy for a mobiel app. The point is - you would need to use CSS+HTML to create a modal window for your app yourself. It isn't baked into PG.